# MySQL query to select rows with a Start and Finish Date and default value as 0000-00-00 00:00:00

Tags: mysql, datetime

I have an articles table (inhered from an old Joomla installation), where there are a Start Publish (**publish_up**) and Finish Publish fields (**publish_down**), the default value for these fields is "0000-00-00 00:00:00" (datetime).

Now I want to select all the rows when the **publish_up** is lower/equal than the current date and **publish_down** is higher/equal than the current date, and also return the values when the **publish_down** have the default value "0000-00-00 00:00:00" (because this means that the user didn't set up a Finish Publish date for that article.

This is que query that I created, although it seems to be working correctly, I'm not sure if it is optimized or if there is a better logic? can you advice please?

```
SELECT of2ab_content.id AS id, of2ab_content.title AS title, of2ab_content.publish_down AS publish_down
FROM of2ab_content, of2ab_categories 
WHERE of2ab_content.catid != ""
AND of2ab_content.catid = of2ab_categories.id 
AND of2ab_content.state=1 
AND of2ab_content.publish_up <= NOW() 
AND (of2ab_content.publish_down >= NOW() 
     OR of2ab_content.publish_down = '0000-00-00 00:00:00') 
ORDER by id DESC
```

Comment: Which DBMS are you actually using? I suspect mysql but either way this is very relevant. https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins

Comment: That's correct, MySQL

Comment: Don't use comma seperated tables in the from clause. Over 25 years ago a better standard was adopted. Use explicit ansi join syntax like `inner join ... on`

Comment: Dont see issue with logic or opportunity for optimization, in any case would need explain plan.assume both date columns are indexed.